# TI SensorTag CC2650 missing 6 out of 11 services

Tags: firmware, sensors

I was doing a project with TI SensorTag CC2650. 
I was able to see 11 services when I got this sensortag. The firmware was v1.20.

After I tried to upgrade the firmware using the IOS app, the device is now missing 6 out of 11 services, including temperature, movements, etc.

The device now has v1.21 version firmware.

I've noticed the local name of the sensor tag changed from "CC2650 SensorTag" to "CC2650 Programmer".

I have tried to use the IOS app to upgrade/rollback the firmware (to v1.30 or back to v1.20). The upgrade was successful and I got a popup dialog on the screen saying "Clear Bluetooth cache and re-connect the app" (at least something like that). But the sensortag just stopped advertising, unless I uninstall and reinstall the battery.

I have no idea how to deal with this. 
Any help on fixing this issue is appreciated